# PHP Version Conflict

Tags: php, windows, wordpress

I am having issues installing WordPress 3.2.1 from my available Web Applications in Plesk.
[Screenshot1 http://www.brightslides.com/picture_library/screen2.jpg](http://www.brightslides.com/picture_library/screen2.jpg)

and I click INSTALL and get this error message: 
Your PHP version (4.4.7) is not suitable for the application.

[Screenshot1 http://www.brightslides.com/picture_library/screen3.jpg](http://www.brightslides.com/picture_library/screen3.jpg)

I have a windows 2008 Server with IIS.

In the Plesk CP, under the domain in question, it shows PHP version 5.2.13 and set to FastCGI.
[Screenshot1 http://www.brightslides.com/picture_library/screen1.jpg](http://www.brightslides.com/picture_library/screen1.jpg)

so whats going on?

Comment: You should be able to uninstall PHP4 through Plesk.

Comment: did you (or anyone else) get to the bottom of this? I have EXACTLY the same problem. Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0):

Please check PHP version which is actually using from your web server. Create a php file in your web directory and paste the following code in file. Browse that file to see PHP version.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If you see php version is not 5.2.13 as said in Plesk, please contact your hosting company.

Comment: ok... its said 5.2.13.